# Need help using compact serialization for JWS(RFC 7515) in flask using python?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

How to use compact serialisation format as per JWS(RFC 7515) for payload in flask using python?

Comment: hey Rahul, welcome to stackoverflow. can you provide an example for the data you want to serialize, or show how to create an object that you want to serialize

Comment: payload={
    "mercid": "BDMERCID",
    "orderid": "order45608988",
    "amount": "300.00",
    "order_date": "2021-03-05T10:59:15+05:30",
    "currency": "356",
    "ru": "https://merchant.com",
    "itemcode": "DIRECT",
    "device": {
        "init_channel": "internet",
        "ip": "124.124.1.1",
        "mac": "11-AC-58-21-1B-AA",
        "imei": "990000112233445",
        "accept_header": "text/html",
        "fingerprintid": "61b12c18b5d0cf901be34a23ca64bb19"
    }
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what is the error when you try to return that as a json? it all seems to be strings and should work

Comment: But how to use JWS(RFC 7515) to encrypt the payload in flask?